# How to save an accessToken in C# WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, access-token

I'm making an WPF application where I have user login. I don't have my own database but i use an rest api to get the needed data. When I login i get an accesstoken. This token is need to get data for the specific user. Right now i save the accesstoken in a static variable, but when I close the app the accesstoken is not saved anymore. Is there a way to save this accesstoken without a database and without to save it in a local file. I use to save in session when I'm developing web apps. Is there a similar way in C# WPF.

Comment: Why don't save token in user settings? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397750%28v=vs.110%29.aspx Eventually this will be a local file, but settings have convenient API to access them.

Comment: Awesome - that works for me :). Make your comment as an answer and I'll approve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Desktop applications can use [user settings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397750%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to save data between launches.
Eventually settings will be stored in a local file, but there is convenient API to access them.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think its possible to do this without using any local files. User/app settings will always use a file somewhere on your machine.

In Web apps your session data is also saved in a file somewhere on your system (user appdata usually).

If you don't want to save it in a file because of security reasons, you could just encrypt it.